# Чёрное изображение при конвертации EMF в BMP

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть следующий код:

```
 string deviceInfo =
             @"<DeviceInfo>
                <OutputFormat>EMF</OutputFormat>
                <PageWidth>58mm</PageWidth>
                <PageHeight>90mm</PageHeight>
                <MarginTop>0mm</MarginTop>
                <MarginLeft>0mm</MarginLeft>
                <MarginRight>0mm</MarginRight>
                <MarginBottom>0mm</MarginBottom>
                </DeviceInfo>";    
byte[] source = report.Render("Image",deviceInfo);
Metafile pageImage = new Metafile(new MemoryStream(source));
pageImage.Save("testpr.bmp", ImageFormat.Bmp);
```

где `report` это экземпляр `Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.LocalReport`. При выполнении `report.Render("Image",deviceInfo);` в `source` возвращается изображение в формате EMF в виде массива байтов.

Проблема возникает на строчке `pageImage.Save("testpr.bmp", ImageFormat.Bmp);` на выходе получается абсолютно чёрное изображение. Если скажем сохранить так:

```
pageImage.Save("testpr.png", ImageFormat.Png)
```

то всё ок.

Предполагаю, что проблема в прозрачности которая есть в EMF...

Вопрос в следующем: Как избавится от "черноты" при сохранении EMF в bmp формате?

Comment: Посмотрите [тут](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/18a86734-3707-45b8-b023-85c0753c9acc/how-to-correctly-convert-emf-to-bmp?forum=winforms). Если поможет и больше никто не даст ответа, то опубликуйте полноценное решение здесь, в качестве ответа. Это поможет другим людям.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По результатам проб и ошибок выяснилось, что проблема в том, что у исходного отчёта LocalReport'а отсутствует фон. Соответственно и изображение, получаемое при рендеринге этого отчёта так же без фона. При конвертации в png и/или jpeg фон добавляется автоматом, а при конвертации в bmp это придётся делать "ручками". Примерно таким образом:

```
string deviceInfo =
             @"<DeviceInfo>
                <OutputFormat>EMF</OutputFormat>
                <PageWidth>58mm</PageWidth>
                <PageHeight>90mm</PageHeight>
                <MarginTop>0mm</MarginTop>
                <MarginLeft>0mm</MarginLeft>
                <MarginRight>0mm</MarginRight>
                <MarginBottom>0mm</MarginBottom>
            </DeviceInfo>";

            byte[] source = LReport.Render("Image", deviceInfo);
            Metafile pageImage = new Metafile(new MemoryStream(source));

            Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(467, 725);
            Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bm);
            System.Drawing.Rectangle imageRect = new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, 467, 725);
            g.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(System.Drawing.Color.White), imageRect);//Добавляем белый фон
            g.DrawImage(pageImage, imageRect);//Рисуем поверх наше изображение
```